# How to prove the elementary inequalities? $||{a+b}|^\alpha - |a|^\alpha| \leq |b|^\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis

For $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$, some $C_\alpha>0$,
\begin{align*}
&\big ||a+b|^\alpha - |a|^\alpha \big |\leq|b|^\alpha,&\quad \text{for }\alpha\leq 1,\\\\
&\big ||a+b|^\alpha - |a|^\alpha \big |\leq C_\alpha\big(|a|^{\alpha-1}+|b|^{\alpha-1} \big)|b|, &\quad \text{for }\alpha>1
\end{align*}
I kindly ask for hints how to prove these inequalities hold true. I could just notice that when $|a+b|^\alpha\geq|a|^\alpha$, then $|a+b|^\alpha\leq|a|^\alpha+|b|^\alpha$, but unfortunately I have no idea of how to e.g. apply the knowledge about the polynomial/exponential function $c^\alpha=e^{\alpha\log c}$ or something else.

Thank you.

Comment: In general $|a+b|^p\leq(|a|+|b|)^p\leq 2^p \max(|a|^p,|b|^p)\leq2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p)$. This also has been addressed before in MSE.

Comment: I proved the first one but the second one is still puzzling me. Can we prove it manipulating only with the left side not taking the right one into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This addresses the second inequality stated by the OP.
The following general inequality will be useful:
$$(1+t)^\alpha\leq 2^\alpha(1+t^\alpha)$$
for all $t\geq0$ and $\alpha\geq0$.

For $p\geq1$, simple integration yields
$$(1+x)^p-1=\int^x_0p(1+t)^{p-1}\,dt\leq p\int^x_02^{p-1}(1+t^{p-1})\,dt\leq p2^{p-1}(x+x^p)$$
Hence
$$(1+x)^p\leq 1+p2^{p-1}(x+x^p)$$
Consequently, for $a>0,b\geq0$
$$\begin{align}
(a+b)^p&=a^p\Big(1+\frac{b}{a}\Big)^p\leq a^p\Big(1+p2^{p-1}\big(\frac{b}{a}+\frac{b^p}{a^p}\big)\Big)\\
&=a^p+ p2^{p-1}\big(a^{p-1}b+b^p\big)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, Oliver!